# Рандом: чем ближе число к нулю, тем чаще оно должно выпадать

Tags: java, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Имеется функция, которая даёт рандомное число в радиусе [-40 .. 40] 
Как сделать так, чтобы числа, близкие к нулю (0, 5, -5) выпадали чаще, чем крайние (40, -35, и т.д.)  ?

Условно можно представить в виде графика **y(x) = -(x*x*0.061)+100**
По горизонтали: число, которое должно выпасть
По вертикали: частота выпадения
[image]

Comment: Так получайте случайное число в интервале [0,100], потом решайте представленное уравнение, находя x и подставляйте случайным образом знак +/-.

Comment: Именно таким образом и настроены игровые аппараты) Случайное не случайно...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Задачу всё-таки решил, но не предложенными вариантами. Итак.
Изначально задача звучит так: **Создать число в промежутке от 6 до 14. Чем число ближе к 10, тем оно должно выпадать чаще** (в самом вопросе я поменял условие задачи, но не суть важно)

Для её решения понадобится два рандомных числа в промежутке [3..7].
Полученные два числа надо сложить друг с другом. Таблица сложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сумма этих двух случайных чисел и есть наше конечное число
В итоге, чем ближе число к 10, тем чаще оно выпадает

Comment: То, что вы написали в ответе, не подходит к условию задачи в вопросе. В вопросе у вас нарисовано непрерывное распределение: оно означает, что и 1 может выпасть, и 1.123, и число пи. А в ответе — дискретное комбинаторное распределение.

Comment: Приношу извинения. Мне не требовалась такая точность и тот график был чисто для примера. Так как это мой первый вопрос на overflow, то я не мог подумать, что мне дадут настолько точный ответ. Впредь буду внимательнее относиться к формулированию вопроса

Answer (score 10):

Имеются алгоритмы, позволяющие получить случайное число с заданным распределением вероятности, но чтобы их применить - надо сначала получить это самое распределение (или его плотность).

Сначала посмотрите на разные распределения и найдите какое вам подходит или нарисуйте свое (то, что вы нарисовали - ни распределением, ни плотностью вероятности не является). Распределение вероятности будет функцией F(X): [-40, 40] → [0, 1), плотность - функцией f(X): [-40; 40] → [0, +∞).

Теперь что с ней можно сделать.

Алгоритм первый, математический. Генерируем случайное число от 0 до 1 стандартными средствами, после чего применяем к нему функцию, обратную F: X = F<sup>-1</sup>(Y), где Y - равномерно распределенное случайное число в интервале [0, 1). Недостатки этого варианта - возможная нехватка точности на сильно неравномерных распределениях и необходимость вычисления обратной функции.

Алгоритм второй, итерационный. Генерируем два обычных случайные числа, первое (X) от 40 до -40, второе (Y) от 0 до максимального значения плотности вероятности. Если f(X) < Y - возвращаем X, иначе - повторяем с начала.

Если вы генерируете целые числа, а не вещественные - то для второго алгоритма надо брать вероятность вместо плотности вероятности.

Answer (score 9):

Представленная вами функция на математическом языке называется *функция распределения плотности вероятности*

Общее правило генерации случайного числа с заданной `F(x)` функцией следующая:

1) Допустим имеется генератор дающий равномерно распределенную рандомную величину от 0 до 1 - обозначим ее как `u`

2) В этом случае ваше случайное значение `x` должно вычисляться как:

```
x=F^-1(u)  //обратная функция от F с аргументом u
```

Для вашего случая это: `x=sqrt((100-u)/0.061)`

P.S. Вообще ваша функция очень похожа на [шапку Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - не извращайтесь со степенной функцией и примените именно ее - нормальное распределение.