# JavaScript Случайное число, но чем оно больше, тем оно реже

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив чисел от 0 до 6 `let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, мне нужно получить случайное число из этого массива, но чем оно больше, то есть дальше в массиве, тем оно реже будет генерироваться. Очень долго пытался сделать, но ничего дельного не вышло, только голова заболела. Если это возможно, то мне нужен максимально маленький и простой код.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707655/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: Просьба не судить строго, сам начинающий JS,скорее задача стоит немного иначе, здесь инициатор должен привести конкретную формулировку задания. Так понимаю из логики описанного выше - нужно задать приоритет каждому элементу массива начиная с 0го индекса, и чем выше индекс тем число попадает в рандом случайного меньше раз.Как на счет рекурсии?

Comment: Вопрос в присланном вами ответе не соответствует текущему

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
    arr2.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
// now generate uniformly for arr2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!